# vb.net : change windows "top" of the screen

Tags: windows, vb.net, controls, screen

I have an application (menu bar) that, when running, puts itself at the top of my screen and everything else that loads, automatically knows to load below that menu bar. Its like the program established a new "top" of the screen and that top starts right below the menu bar. I want to duplicate this functionality in vb.net. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Basically, I'm looking for something to tell windows the top of the screen starts below my program. I hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following project by Arik Poznanski

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3

Take this code, compile, and add it to your project as a reference.  Then in the form load

```
Me.Edge = AppBarEdges.Top   'sets the form to dock at the top of the screen
```

This sets it to the top of the screen with everything else below.

Comment: You can always convert the code to VB.  Or just compile and add to a VB project.  That's what I did.

Comment: I'm fairly new to VB. How do I compile a C# program? and then what exactly am I making a reference to in my VB program? Which file, the exe? or does it compile into a dll? I know how to make a reference to another file, I just don't know what I am looking for.

Comment: Download C# Express.  Compile the files.  Then, in your VB program, Add a reference to the dll that is created when you compiled the C# code.

Comment: I now have a reference to the ShellBasics.dll file in my vb.net project. But when I try to use the code "Me.Edge..." It says that 'Edge is not a member or Form1'. Sorry for the questions, but I really want to get this working. Where do I put the 'Me.Edge...' code? I tried at the beginning of the Class and also in the Form1_load Sub, but both gave errors.

Comment: The form you want docked has to be of type ShellLib.ApplicationDesktopToolbar.  You can do this in your current code on the first line of your Form  "Public Class frmMenu : Inherits ShellLib.ApplicationDesktopToolbar"

Comment: I now have a different error: Error Base class 'ShellLib.ApplicationDesktopToolbar' specified for class 'Main_Form' cannot be different from the base class 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' of one of its other partial types. How do I fix this?

Comment: I Finally got it working. I had to change the Inherits line the form.designer.vb file to match the one you gave me. Thanks for sticking with me. This is great.